# getMaximumSize() for dual screen

Tags: java, swing

if you have a dual screen computer, how do I make my program open to fill the screen just on my main monitor? If I use the getMaximumSize() method, it extends to my second screen?

```
frame.setSize(frame.getMaximumSize());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size from the graphics configuration.

```
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;  
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;  
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;  

public class GuiScreens {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();  
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();  
        GraphicsConfiguration[] gc = gs[0].getConfigurations();  
        System.out.println("    Bounds: " + gc[0].getBounds());  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Toolkit#getScreenSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize%28%29) to determine the screen size, and set the frame to that size